# Can a co-leader demote the leader and promote himself to leader

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have not played coc for around 20 days because of private problem, can a co-leader demote the leader and promote himself to leader.

Answer (score 8):

No, a co-leader cannot demote a leader. A member of any rank can only demote/kick another member of lesser rank, except in the case of leaders, who can demote themselves and promote someone else, however no one else can demote the leader.

Source: personal experience from running my clan.

Answer (score -3):

No, it is impossible for a co-leader to demote leader and promote himself to leader, it is obvious because leader only should have power to make any other person leader.

And if are afraid that a co-leader will demote you(assuming that you are leader), do not worry, they will not demote you, they might leave your clan due to your inactiveness.

Source- https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=other-clan-stuff&f=our-clan-leader-is-never-online

Comment: This adds nothing not already said.